# java- Sending data over network for iso8583

Tags: java

Im trying to send iso8583 data over a network connection, currently when i send the data it is showing in TCP viewer as one long string

but it should look like this

```
0000(0000)  30 38 30 30 82 38 00 00  00 00 00 00 04 00 00 00   0800.8..........
0016(0010)  00 00 00 00 30 38 32 34  31 30 35 31 30 30 31 33   ....082410510013
0032(0020)  35 31 30 30 31 33 35 31  30 30 30 38 32 34 33 30   5100135100082430
0048(0030)  31                                                 1
```

my code for sending the data

```
Socket plug = new Socket(Config.getServerIP(), Config.getServerPort());
DataInputStream In= new DataInputStream(plug.getInputStream());
PrintWriter Out = new PrintWriter(plug.getOutputStream());

String Indata, Outdata;
Outdata =" ";
Indata = "NOTHING";

while (!Outdata.equals("Bye"))
{
  Outdata=message;
  Out.write(Outdata);
  Out.flush();

  if (!Outdata.equals("Bye"))
  {
    Indata=In.readLine();
    System.out.println(Indata);
  }
}
In.close();
Out.close();
```

Does the data have to be sent in a specific way?
Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure this is the code for sending the data? Looks like it receives something and prints it on `System.out`.

Comment: Looks abit weird to me. Do you want to communicate over a network connection between two java processes, or are you intending to use the loopback interface?

Comment: (off-topic) Java naming conventions are the classes are written as `UppercaseStartingCamelCase` and fields/variables are written as `lowercaseStartingCamelCase`. Consequently, you should name `Outdata` as `outData` and `Indata` and `inData`. Also, `In` should be `in` and `Out` should be `out`.

Comment: So you expect "Out.write(Outdata);" to output in ISO 8583 format? But what sort of class is PrintWriter? If it is the usual java.io.PrintWriter then that has no ISO 8583 capability.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the problem was that i had to write the output using a byte array of integers, this in turn shows in TCP viewer as Hex data, the next issue i faced was that any integer in the byte array over 128 was causing an overflow to by pass that i had to use the following methods

```
Socket server = new Socket(Config.getServerIP(), Config.getServerPort());
bytes = packData(bytes);
    server.getOutputStream().write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
```

then the packData method

```
static byte[] packData(byte[] data) {
    int len = data.length;
    byte buf[] = new byte[len + 2];
    buf[0] = (byte) (len >> 8 & 255);
    buf[1] = (byte) (len & 255);
    System.arraycopy(data, 0, buf, 2, len);
    return buf;
}
```

Hope this helps someone